# Move data from a column to seven days in advance - pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with 2 columns. One of them is the index in date format and the other one is a rate R (a number between 0 and 1). How can I add another column to the pandas Dataframe that contains the rate R for the one-week before day?

So at the end I have the dates, the rate of that day and the rate of the (day-7 days) of the DataFrame?

Comment: Can you add some data sample? 4-5 rows is nice.

Comment: but `df['new'] = df['R'].shift(7, freq='d')` should work

Comment: Thanks jezrael, that was it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas shift like this:

```
df['newColumn'] = df['RateColumn'].shift(7)
```

Keep in mind that first 7 values of the new column will be Nans as there are no data for them.